# Compare values of two columns as less than or equal and get selected rows in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Someone please help me... I have a mysql database table in which I am storing user_id , total_installments and paid_installments of individual users and now I want a query to select all those user_ids whose paid_installments is less than their total installments. I tried the query...SELECT user_id from installments_tbl where paid_installments < total_installments;
I know this query is wrong but I want this type of query or any method result
Please help me..
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your query is correct.

```
SELECT `user_id` FROM installments_tbl 
WHERE `paid_installments` < `total_installments`
```

Check this working example :

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11002/3